# Using Kotlin and exposed, trying to map one-to-one relation using a link table

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to do a OneToOne relation between two entities using a link table. I have a User and Role entities and as per the current requirement, each user has exactly one role although in future, it may change. So I am mapping the user and role relation using the link table.

So far I have created user table

```
object UserTable: LongIdTable("users", "internal_id") {
    val username = varchar("username", 100).uniqueIndex()
    val email = varchar("email", 100).uniqueIndex()
    val name = varchar("name", 100)
    val password = varchar("password", 250)
    val lastActivityTimestamp = datetime("last_activity_timestamp")
    val externalId = uuid("external_id").uniqueIndex()
    val createdBy = varchar("created_by", 100)
    val lastModifiedBy = varchar("last_modified_by", 100)
    val createdTimestamp = datetime("created_timestamp")
    val lastModifiedTimestamp = datetime("last_modified_timestamp").index()
    val status = varchar("status", 10).index()
}
```

as well as the role table

```
object RoleTable: LongIdTable("roles", "internal_id") {
    val name = varchar("name", 100).uniqueIndex()
    val identifier = varchar("identifier", 100)
    val landingPageUri = varchar("landing_page_uri", 250)
    val mappedRolesJson = varchar("mapped_roles_json", 250)
    val externalId = uuid("external_id").uniqueIndex()
    val createdBy = varchar("created_by", 100)
    val lastModifiedBy = varchar("last_modified_by", 100)
    val createdTimestamp = datetime("created_timestamp")
    val lastModifiedTimestamp = datetime("last_modified_timestamp").index()
    val status = varchar("status", 10).index()
}
```

I also created the link table as

```
object UserAuthorityTable: Table("user_authorities") {
    val user = reference("user_id", UserTable)
    val role = reference("role_id", RoleTable)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(
        user, role
    )
}
```

I ended up creating the Role entity as

```
class Role(internalId: EntityID<Long>) : LongEntity(internalId) {
    companion object : LongEntityClass<Role>(RoleTable)
    var name by RoleTable.name
    var identifier by RoleTable.identifier
    var landingPageUri by RoleTable.landingPageUri
    var mappedRolesJson by RoleTable.mappedRolesJson
    var externalId by RoleTable.externalId
    var createdBy by RoleTable.createdBy
    var lastModifiedBy by RoleTable.lastModifiedBy
    var createdTimestamp by RoleTable.createdTimestamp
    var lastModifiedTimestamp by RoleTable.lastModifiedTimestamp
    var status by RoleTable.status
}
```

and the user entity as

```
class User(internalId: EntityID<Long>) : LongEntity(internalId) {
    companion object : LongEntityClass<User>(UserTable)
    var username by UserTable.username
    var email by UserTable.email
    var name by UserTable.name
    var password by UserTable.password
    var role by Role via UserAuthorityTable
    var lastActivityTimestamp by UserTable.lastActivityTimestamp
    var externalId by UserTable.externalId
    var createdBy by UserTable.createdBy
    var lastModifiedBy by UserTable.lastModifiedBy
    var createdTimestamp by UserTable.createdTimestamp
    var lastModifiedTimestamp by UserTable.lastModifiedTimestamp
    var status by UserTable.status
}
```

but obviously that manifests as role expecting a SizedIterable inside user.
How can I map the link table relation as a "singular"?

I want the User entity to have a reference to a single instance of Role mapped through a link table instead of a join column and need guidance on how to achieve the same through Exposed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `via`, that represents many-to-many relationship, you should use `referencedOn`:

```kotlin
class User(internalId: EntityID<Long>) : LongEntity(internalId) {
    ...
    var role by Role referencedOn UserAuthorityTable.role
    ...
}
```

Note that you also need to specify the column you use as the reference.